# Plotting a complicated function containing special functions

Tags: plotting, special-functions

I am new to *Mathematica* and I'm trying to plot the following analytical function at few time steps (say t=0.1, 0.5, 1, 10) all in one plot (similar to `hold on` in MATLAB).

$$\begin{align*}
p(x;t)=\frac1{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi t}}&\left[\exp\left(-\frac{(x-x_0-\mu t)^2}{2\sigma^2 t}\right)+\exp\left(\frac{-4x_0\mu t-(x+x_0-\mu t)^2}{2\sigma^2 t}\right)+\right.\\&\left.\frac{2\mu}{\sigma^2}\exp\left(\frac{2\mu x}{\sigma^2}\right)\left\{1-\Phi\left(\frac{x+x_0+\mu t}{\sigma \sqrt t}\right)\right\}\right]
\end{align*}$$

This function is from [page 224 (with some typos corrected)](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=NeR5JEunGYwC&pg=PA224) of the book:

> Cox, D. R., and H. D. Miller. *The Theory of Stochastic Processes*. Vol. 134. CRC Press, 1977.

Note that the function $\Phi[(x+x_0+\mu t)/(\sigma \sqrt t)]$ is the integral from $-\infty$ to $x$ as:

$$\Phi(x)=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^x e^{-\frac12 y^2}\mathrm dy$$

I am aware of *Mathematica*'s error function `Erf` and Normal Distribution but they integrate from $0$ to $x$ and my function is from $-\infty$ to $x$.

Here is what I have for a code as an initial one-time trial with some parameters.

```
ClearAll[μ, σ, t, z, z0, f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f];      
z0 = 0.01; μ = 0.1; σ = 1; t = 10;
f1 := 1/(σ*Sqrt[2*π*t])
f2[z_] := Exp[-((z - z0 - μ*t)^2)/(2*t*σ^2)];
f3[z_] := Exp[(-4*z0*μ*t - (z + z0 - μ*t)^2)/(2*t*σ^2)];
f4[z_] := (2*μ)/σ^2*Exp[(2*μ*z)/σ^2];
f5[z] := Integrate[Exp[-1/2 ((u + z0 + μ*t)/(σ Sqrt[t]))^2]/Sqrt[2 π], {u, -∞, z}]
(*f6[z_]:=Simplify[f5,t>0];*)
f = f1[z]*(f2[z] + f3[z] + f4[z]*(1 - f5[z]))
```

> ```
> (1/(10 Sqrt[2 π]))[z] 
>   (E^(1/200 (-0.4 - (-9.99 + z)^2)) + E^(- (1/200) (-10.01 + z)^2) + 
>     0.2 E^(0.2 z) 
>       (1 - 
>          ((5. - 1.32904*10^-15 I) + 
>            (0.353553 (10.01 + 1. z) Erf[0.0707107 Sqrt[(10.01 + 1. z)^2]]) / 
>               Sqrt[(0.707814 + 0.0707107 z)^2])[z]))
> ```

```
Plot[{f[z]}, {z, z0, 10}]
```

[image: my attempt]

which is not working (I use `z` for `x` here). The function should be real, but my answer has an imaginary part.

Comment: Please put your code as text that can be copied by other people (select your code in *Mathematica* and right-click: Copy As > Input Text), and not as pictures. Otherwise, people are less likely to help you.

Comment: Also, note that `Erf[]` and `NormalDistibution[]` are built-in, which may help simplify your code.

Comment: "*Mathematica*'s error function is from $0$ to $x$." - that's why two-argument `Erf[]` is supported: `Φ[x_] := Erf[-∞, x/Sqrt[2]]/2`

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I tried copying the code as "Input Text" but it still looks weird on this screen. I wonder if it has to do with how I am copying it here as code. Thanks

Comment: It's fine; the point is to not make people have to retype everything you did, as that decreases the chances of people helping you.

Comment: I forgot to add: please add a reference (book, paper, etc.) for the formula you were trying to plot.

Comment: Not sure why you say "I am aware of *Mathematica*'s error function `Erf` and Normal Distribution but they integrate from 0 to x and my function is from −∞ to x."  The function `CDF[NormalDistribution[0,1],x]` is identical to $\Phi(x)$.

Comment: Thanks Jim. I edited my question so the function is corrected now.Please see the p(x,t) in my question

Comment: @Jim, partly my fault, sorry for confusing you. I $\TeX$'d up the OP's formula, while incorporating his comments about the typos in the original reference, but neglected to indicate that the formula was corrected.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed some of the function definitions and changed enforced evaluation of `Integrate` at the time of definition with `Evaluate` (otherwise the `Plot` takes forever as the symbolic integration has to be done over and over again).

```
ClearAll[μ, σ, t, z, z0, f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f];
z0 = 0.01; μ = 0.1; σ = 1; t = 10;
f1[z_] := 1/(σ*Sqrt[2*π*t])
f2[z_] := Exp[-((z - z0 - μ*t)^2)/(2*t*σ^2)];
f3[z_] := Exp[(-4*z0*μ*t - (z + z0 - μ*t)^2)/(2*t*σ^2)];
f4[z_] := (2*μ)/σ^2*Exp[(2*μ*z)/σ^2];
f5[z_] := Evaluate[Integrate[
   Exp[-1/2 ((u + z0 + μ*t)/(σ Sqrt[t]))^2]/
    Sqrt[2 π], {u, -∞, z}]]
(*f6[z_]:=Simplify[f5,t>0];*)

f[z_] := f1[z]*(f2[z] + f3[z] + f4[z]*(1 - f5[z]))

Plot[{f[z]}, {z, z0, 10}]
```

At least, this returns plot.

Comment: Thanks Henrik. This is a Probability density function and hence should be between 0 and 1.

Comment: @Khaled Probability density functions are not limited to be between 0 and 1 (although cumulative distribution functions are limited to that range).

Comment: `f5[z_]` could be changed to `f5[z_]:=CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], (z + z0 + \[Mu] t)/(\[Sigma] Sqrt[t])]` or `1/2 Erfc[-((z + z0 + t \[Mu])/(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[t]))]`.